# In Python, why does the dictonary value of a variable in a class change, while not the variable itself?

Tags: python

I was recently trying to write and manipulate a class in Python and I came across an odd situation.  Whenever I try to manipulate a variable of an instantiation of a class, it only affects the variable in the location where it was change.  For example:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test1 = 0
        self.location = {"test1":self.test1}
        self.row = [self.test1]
def change():
    a = test()  #instantiation
    a.location['test1'] = 1 #Changing a.test1 to 1 within a dictionary
    print(a.test1) #Print a.test
    print(a.location['test1']) #Print a.test1 from within the dictionary where it was changed
    print(a.row) #Print a list also containing a.test1
change()
```

Outputs to:

```
0 #Variable itself is unchanged
1 #Variable in dictionary is changed
[0] #Same variable referenced in list is unchanged as well
```

Why does this happen and how could I change a.test1 to equal 1 by only changing it through the dictionary?

Comment: By reassigning the value, you are not reassigning the actual attribute.

Comment: You seem to think that the references to `self.test1` in your class are somehow creating permanent references to the instance variable.  They are not.  Those references are equivalent to just using `0`.  With that understanding, the behavior should now be obvious.

Comment: "there is no way to ever link a variable to another variable in Python" - Learning Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because python integers are immutable. So, every time you do any operation with integer - it's actually creates new object instead of create pointer to prevoius object. This could be easyly illustraded with following code:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = a
>>> b += 1
>>> a, b
(0, 1)
```

But, if you would use lists, for example, you would get something like this:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(1)
>>> a, b
([1], [1])
```

In summing up - your code work as it should. Also, i suggest you to try following snippet:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test1 = [0]
        self.location = {"test1": self.test1}
        self.row = [self.test1]


def change():
    a = test()  #instantiation
    a.location['test1'][0] = 1  #Changing a.test1 to 1 within a dictionary
    print(a.test1) #Print a.test
    print(a.location['test1'])  #Print a.test1 from within the dictionary where it was changed
    print(a.row)    #Print a list also containing a.test1

change()
```

Which would produce you:

```
[1]
[1]
[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing what self.location["test1"] is equal to doesn't change the value of self.test1.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test1 = 0
        self.location = {"test1":self.test1}
        self.row = [self.test1]


def change():
    a = test() 
    a.location['test1'] = a.test1 = 1
    a.row = [a.test1]
    print(a.test1)
    print(a.location['test1'])
    print(a.row)


change()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning the value to the dictionary you are replacing the `self.test1` reference.  As far as I know there is no way to 'point' to the dictionary value, or store a reference to it.  If any one knows otherwise, please enlighten me.